# magento 1.8 store view language specific

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, language-package, multi-language

app/locale/My_Language is right there, but 80% of front-end displays in English.

My_Langage is set up in Back End though.

I guess back end needs more tweaking. Any leads?

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Please check with below url, which is provide step by step to setup your own language via admin configuration.
https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006305808-How-to-create-a-Multi-Language-Store-in-Magento-Tutorial-

Comment: it's arabic. 
edit: works 95% now.
But still 5% missing. example: 'Your cart is empty' is in english.

Answer (score 0):

1- You need to create a new store view and set the desired translation to this store view.
2- Set Locale Option of Store View.
3- Configure language for CMS pages and static blocks.

Be sure to clear the cache before trying to use your new language.
For more detail, follow these links:

https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/language-add.html

https://www.ubertheme.com/docs/setup-multiple-languages-currencies/ 
http://inchoo.net/magento/adding-a-new-language-in-magento/

Hope this helps.